# FrameLayout не хочет подвязываться к нижнему концу Toolbar в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout, framelayout

В общем я хочу испольтзовать сразу NavigationView и BottomNavigationView в activity.Сделал следующую верстку.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">




        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/toolbar"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/title_home"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />


            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_background"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/card_profile_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >




    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Проблема в том, что FrameLayout залазит на Toolbar хотя указано что он должен подвязываться к низу  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar".В чем может быть проблема? И еще возможно есть более простое решение использования сразу NavigationView и BottomNavigationView, но я что то ничего проще не нашел.

Comment: Попробуйте все остальные привязки указать. Т.е. верх тулбара привязать к родителю. Низ FrameLayout к верху BottomNavigationView. И поставить высоту FrameLayout  в `0dp`

Comment: Я сделал так но появилось две проблемы. 1. Если список RecycleView во FrameLayout маленький BottomNavigationView показывается по середине экрана http://prntscr.com/p08oq1.  2. А если список большой то BottomNavigationView уплывает за экран и до него не добраться как и до последних элементов RecycleView http://prntscr.com/p08p0a ))

Answer (score 1):

Юрий все правильно посоветовал я привязал bottomNavigationView к низу FrameLayout, А надо наоборот. Вот код:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">




        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/toolbar"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="@string/title_home"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"/>


            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_background"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/card_profile_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >




    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```